# Firebase login with email giving "auth/wrong-password" for a Google account

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm using Firebase Auth, with email and Google providers enabled.

I have an account that's registered with a Google provider: "foo@gmail.com". There is no password associated with it, since it's a Google account.

If a user tries to use email/password to log in with "foo@gmail.com", using `signInWithEmailAndPassword`, it results in a `auth/wrong-password` error code (no matter what password is entered, of course).

This seems strange to me, as I would expect some error like "auth/different-provider", so I could nudge the user towards logging in correctly.

Is there a way where I can tell that this operation failed due to using a different provider? Or is it opaque from the perspective of the client?

Comment: You would need to offer the user all the login-options on the login screen. `signInWithEmailAndPassword` works with project based email authentication only. Email authentication has no idea about other, potential providers. https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/google-signin

Comment: Both options are there, but I'm concerned about the user forgetting the registered with Google, and trying to sign in with email. I'd like to tell the user "Try signing in with Google instead" if that happens. But the error just says wrong password, it doesn't indicate that the attempt was using the wrong provider.

Comment: I see. As the providers do not share data, one would have to write a wrapper that checks the other providers for potential logins / accounts already established. Not sure if all providers offer that insight, as that would indicate potential privacy issues.

Comment: @Nathan auth/wrong-password is a code of a message. Read the message you get from it. https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/v8/firebase.auth.Auth#signinwithemailandpassword

Comment: Use `auth/wrong-password` code to internationalize application (Translate error codes to different languages.) and read by your self and send to users a message it gives.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*firebaser here*

The idea of the Firebase API is that you ask the user for their email address first (since that is the primary identifier) and then (if your app allows signing in with different provider(s)) you call [`fetchSignInMethodsForEmail`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/auth.md#fetchsigninmethodsforemail)  to determine with which provider(s) that email address can sign in.

If you follow this flow, the code will only show the Google sign-in for the user, since that's the only provider `fetchSignInMethodsForEmail` will return.

You can of course also use the API within your current flow to detect the mismatch yourself and show an error message, but the flow above is what the API is designed for and what (for example) the Firebase-UI libraries implement.

Comment: Thanks! I'm now invoking this on "auth/wrong-password", and telling the user "Try Log In with Google Instead".

I want to use best practices like you suggest, but it seems strange to ask the user for their email before Log In with Google; most sites I've seen just have a single "Log In With Google" button, and the user (who is likely already logged into their google account) doesn't have to enter their email or really even think what their email is. 

Do you have any example apps/sites that ask for the email first before Log In with Google? I'll look into the Firebase-UI libraries.

Comment: If you don't think of different providers, but of authentication factors, Google's own sites are actually a good example of this. They first ask for your email address, so that they can determine how your account is supposed to sign in (usually by asking for a password next, but that is by no means a given anymore these days).